# 'clientEvents' decreases start time automatically

Tags: fullcalendar

Problem with clientEvents

```
var tempEventWithOlderInfo = calendar.fullCalendar( 'clientEvents' ,'_fc798' )[0];

alert( 'start time: '+ tempEventWithOlderInfo.start.getHours() );
```

This alerts the wrong time. If the start time of event is 6:30 PM. The above code would alert **5** instead of **6**.
I am not sure why **clientEvents** method isn't returning the correct time.

Comment: Can you please add the part where you add this event to the calendar? What timezone is your computer set to?

Comment: This is in the click method of 'Submit' button of my dialog box. I used jQuery dialog box to get event details from the user. My computer is in GMT +5

Comment: Also when I debug the **eventClick** callback of the fullCalendar. The same event has the correct start time there. I guess this is some bug in fullCalendar.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `clientEvents` is fine, never had any kind of issue with it. But you can always report this as a bug at https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar - and just an idea: What does `alert(calendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents' ,'_fc798').length);` output?

Comment: It alerts '1'. Also it makes sense. In fact **clientEvents** returns the array of events that match the provided filter. In my case the filter is an event ID. So it returns the array of length one, containing only one event.

Comment: Ok, I thought that you could have maybe actually had more than one event with this ID, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: I went to: https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar to report the issue. But I couldn't figure out where to report the issue. I've never used github. Can you please guide me to the page where I can report that issue? does it require any kind of special permissions?

Answer (score 0):

No need for a bug report here. getHours() returns the hour of the day as indexed from 0.

The full range of values getHours() can return is 0-23. Just increment your result by 1 to get the actual hour.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp

Comment: OK, but what do you think, why does the above two lines work fine in eventClick method and other methods of FullCalendar? I face this issue whenever I use this code outside the code of FullCalendar.